# How do I pass a value from main html to partials?

Tags: angularjs

The main file (index.php) has some session information like user name that I would like to use in the partials (views). These are static html files and I prefer to keep them static.

I could make a call to server from the controller of the partial to get the data. But I have the information when the main page loads and they don't change later when the partials are loaded.

How can place this information on the main html and then pass on to the controllers of the partials when they load?

PS: I am using AngularJS 1.1.5 (Recently started learning AngularJS)

Update: I tried a service with a controller on the main page setting value and controllers for partials trying to read. I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

In your index.php/html/whatever include a script tag with an Angular service that captures and returns your data.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Include Angular -->

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // By creating this service, we can capture the data from
            // from the server and store it.
            angular.module('myApp').factory('usrData', [function () {

                var data = {};

                data.usrData = <?php echo $usrService->getUserData(); ?>;

                return data;
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Continue with HTML -->
```

Then, you can have another service, say in service.js, that you use to collect your inline data that you captured from your server as well as other data you've queried through AJAX and create an API to manage it all. You do this by injecting the inlined service from your HTML as a dependency into this `dataServices` module:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('dataServices', [

    '$http', 'otherData', 'usrData', // <-- These are the module dependencies

    function ($http, otherData, usrData) { // <-- Here you use them as parameters

        'use strict';

        var dataModel = {

            otherData: otherData,
            usrData: usrData
        };

        return { // Data service API

            query: function (dataType) {

                // returns data

                // API continues …
```

Lastly, in your controller, say controller.js, you inject this `dataServices` service as a dependency to retrieve and save your data through this API:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('UsrWidget', [

    '$scope', 'dataServices',

    function ctrlrPtHeader($scope, dataServices) {

        "use strict";

        $scope.usrData = dataServices.query('usrData');

        // And now you have the data.
```

Now, the controller *could* directly access the usrData service that is inlined into you HTML, but I prefer more of a global API to manage my data by providing a nice API script and keeping my HTML as clean as possible. The secret to the whole thing is encapsulating all your data inside of Angular's environment and just pass the information around with dependency injection and factory methods.

Comment: It works. I had to place that script after including my controller code. Said "no module 'myApp'" if I had it before. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know it worked for you. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Gone are the days of inline php --- including session data.

What you want to do, is create a service object that calls your "server side app" for "all" data, you can even bind sessions to JSON objects if you want too.

This service object needs to be shared by other partials, which will most likely have their own controllers. To do this, you need the ability to **[share data between controllers](http://ramandv.com/blog/angular-js-sharing-data/)** on the service object.

Comment: There is a certain level of processing on the server before deciding to send the initial content down. In some cases, there is a redirect to somewhere else. That processing results in data that can be pushed down. If I make a server call to get all that data, I will be duplicating the processing. My premise may be wrong though.

Comment: @user2429270 You could also take a look at `$cookieFactory`

Comment: Thanks Dan. I will look at both suggestions.